# How to separate the EXE header and the encrypted message of a PGP SDA using Python?

Tags: python, exe, pgp

I have both PGP Self Decrypting Archive EXE file and their password. It is my understanding that correspond to an EXE header and the encrypted message.

How can I separate the encrypted message for further processing?

I'm trying to use PEReader, but I have no idea how identify neither the content not the EXE header.

Comment: This is implementation-defined and subject to change without notice; the OpenPGP standard doesn't specify any self-decrypting archive mechanism (nor should it: self-decrypting archives are, from a security perspective, an utterly horrid idea: if you don't trust your communication channel not to have someone listening in, how can you trust it not to have someone replacing your executable with a malicious one?)

Comment: Regardless of my opinion on the matter, unfortunately this is a problem in my job where I am asked to decompress several PGP SDA, but in Linux so it seemed to me the best way to start investigating using Python to eventually create a process.

Comment: might be worth figuring out what program the file came from, also what format "EXE" are you talking about?  I'm assuming a MS Windows x86-64 PE but some details would help!  if you somewhat trust the files you could use Wine and see if they have some command line interface, otherwise spin up a VM if you're less trusting.

Comment: If you're given an assertion that the executable is trusted (ugh), I agree with Sam -- the easy way out of this is to run it with WINE. (Assuming it can run from the CLI, might be able to pull it off in Docker or another limited-access container).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Docker isn't designed to be a security barrier and without special care it's often worse than running a program as a regular user (or it always used to be anyway!).  if OP is concerned about provenance I'd suggest using something like KVM which is actually designed with isolation in mind

Comment: @SamMason, ...with privileged mode enabled I fully agree. Otherwise... eh, it's pretty close to a typical chroot jail + single-purpose user account + set of restricted `nsenter` namespaces (which I agree isn't a strong barrier in the way a proper VM is, but Windows malware is written to infect _Windows_, not to leverage Linux kernel exploits / jail escapes / etc). It'd be different if we were using files created by an attacker who _knew_ this was the execution environment, of course; but if we're exclusively unpacking things that were created in the past before this execution environment[...]

Comment: [...]was created (and, as of present moment, discussed in a public forum), I find this a place where a shrug and a "probably good 'nuff" is liable to suffice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yup, agree.  that said, it's certainly possible for an attacker to write code that targets Wine (or whatever else you use) but unless you're going up against a state-level attacker (at which point you certainly have bigger issues) shrugging and saying "it'll probably be fine" will indeed probably be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You began with `horrible.exe` plus the `"secret-password"` key,
which you used to produce `clear.bin`.

> How can I separate the encrypted message for further processing?

You know the encryption algorithm and can use key plus `clear.bin`
to produce `cipher.bin`.
Assume the self-extractor did not do any annoying XOR or other
trivial transform of `cipher.bin`.

At this point, your task is to identify a substring of `horrible.exe`
that matches some or all of `cipher.bin`,
modulo perhaps some header details such as timestamps.
So pick several bytes from the middle of `cipher.bin`
and go searching. Then verify that extending the cipher byte range
will readily give you a bigger match of self-extractor bytes.

The end result is you want file offsets or some simple
copying algorithm that lets you turn an untrusted self-extracting .EXE
into `cipher.bin`, suitable for subsequent decryption in the usual way.

---

You may find it convenient to produce
a small `$ echo Hello world  > clear.bin` document,
turn that into both `cipher.bin` plus a self-extracting .EXE,
and work through the details until you're confident you can do it
for arbitrary cleartext documents
and are ready to graduate to the big one.
And then [describe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
your findings.

@CharlesDuffy comments that
the [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)
may be sand in the Vaseline.
So definitely encrypt "Hello world" at least twice using same key,
and note the differences.

@SamMason observes that e.g. diff'ing SEA executables
for cleartext "Hell" and cleartext "Hello"
would likely reveal the common x86 preamble.
Knowing how many prefix bytes to ignore
would bring you a little closer to your goal.

Comment: PGP creates some random salt, so using the same key every time won't create the same ciphertext every time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Uggh! (smacks forehead loudly) Sooo, part of the "simple copying algorithm" is recovering the pepper, perhaps? (Put another way, the inputs are cleartext + key + pepper.)

Comment: In theory, I'd expect the executable contents to contain the full PGP packets with all their wrappers &c, so we _should_ just be able to recover them verbatim. Might even  be able to look for the framing.

Comment: There are common ways of appending data onto most executable formats — often it's enough to just append it onto the end of the executable.  when the program runs it can figure out how big it was supposed to be, and then use that information to pull out the "encrypted" tail for processing

Comment: @SamMason I misused the word "pepper" in a comment I corrected within the edit window; mea culpa there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There's also (even though very naive) case the executable was created in a very simple way - shove large string into a global/static var in a consistent place. In that case objdump might help with the frame identification and if the exe creation process is the same, it might be *assumed* there will be the same frame/variable ending e.g. `content = "..."; windowTitle = "abc";` (ofc in binary representation). Very naive, yet a food for thought :)

Comment: @PeterBadida that would mean the archive creation tool would likely need a (stripped down) compiler and linker which seems like a lot of work